# Cyanogenmod: Profile redundancy?

Tags: cyanogenmod, vibration, profiles, silent-mode

I use Cyanogenmod profiles (on a Galaxy S2).

I've created a couple of custom profiles, "Silent" and "Totally Silent", and I switch to them by doing a long press on the power button. But I've noticed something disturbing: At the bottom of the dialog, there are 3 icons: A speaker with a cross over it, a vibrating phone, and a speaker. These look suspiciously like my profiles. When I switch to "Totally Silent", the icon gets switched to a vibrating phone. But when I switch back to default, it doesn't switch back to the speaker!

What's going on? Are there 2 separate profile selections? I want to have just one place where I set the profile, not two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profiles are just a way to change a bunch of settings at once. By long-pressing the power button and tapping ring/vibrate/silent (below airplane mode) you change a single setting however: The ringing behaviour.

The profiles work slightly different to what you expect.
You most probably forgot to enable some switches of the *standard* profile, most of them are on/off settings for which a profile has 3 actions:

- activate
- deactivate
- modify / do-not-modify

This is for example very handy for a car mode that you activate to **just** switch off a security lock screen (+ enable GPS and leave all else as is).

The standard profile has a lot of those unset **do-not-modify** checkboxes (the checkboxes to the right), so unless you check them the profile doesn't actually change those settings.

Tick the checkbox and try again!

[image]